# app crashes in real phone but works in emulator

Tags: java, android, android-layout

Hi i am new to android prgramming, so i wrote this simple code just to try it, 
it works just fine in android studio emulator but when i use build apk and 
install the app manually on my phone it crashes when i tap on the button i tried it in few phones with android 7, android 5 and andorid 4.4 all gave me the same result.
I use android studio 3.0 and the minimum api i used android 4.0.3 for this project. what could be the problem.

```
package com.example.adem.myapplication;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
    void tst(View v) {
        TextView t= this.findViewById(R.id.temo);
        t.setText("he");
    }
}
```

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.adem.myapplication.MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/temo"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="168dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="164dp"
    android:text="Button"
    android:onClick="tst"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: and you get no error message?

Comment: i just get Unfortantly, My Application has stopped.

Comment: there has to be more, somewhere

Comment: where i can find the log or the details because i am new to programming.

Comment: the error is on phone not android studio emulator.

Comment: Read this: https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/am-logcat.html

Comment: When your app crashes check android monitor or run for logs

Comment: Filter your logcat by errors logs. Then you should find stacktrace easily.

Comment: i used build apk and installed it manually on my phone not by avd manager

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: the app crashes when i click on the button not when the app loads

Comment: Set your phone on debug mode(on developer options). Then plug it to computer. Launch Android Studio and set error filter on your logcat. Launch app and press button. You will find your stacktrace and then send it.

Comment: thanks i got the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thank you guys for replying i found the problem that i was not setting function tst to public 
this the solution

```
public void tst(View view){
    TextView t= this.findViewById(R.id.temo);
    t.setText("he");
}
```